# Question about canonical divergence on a dually flat manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, it.information-theory, manifolds, information-geometry

[image]

I am reading "Methods of Information geometry by Shun-Ichi-Amari" (chapter 3 sec 3.4) and I am stuck here, can someone explain or give any resource about how we got equation $(3.53)$?